# Are "One Shot" Property Getters considered an acceptable coding standard in .NET (or in general)

Tags: c#, .net, properties, activemq-classic

Recently while doing some work with C# & ActiveMQ (via the Apache.NMS libraryies) I came across the following property on the `ActiveMQBytesMessage`

```
public new byte[] Content
{
  get
  {
    byte[] buffer = (byte[]) null;
    this.InitializeReading();
    if (this.length != 0)
    {
      buffer = new byte[this.length];
      this.dataIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    return buffer;
  }
  ..(setter omitted)
}
```

The `InitialiseReading` method handled the connection & streaming of the data from active MQ into the `.dataIn` field. The problem though was that **IT DID THIS EVERYTIME**. And once that data was read, it could never be read again and the dataIn field was zero'd and reset. So simply by observing the property and observing it again, you lost the data. This made for some very strange bugs such as:

```
byte [] myBytes = new byte[msg.Content.Length]; 
//Touched the property. Data read in.

msg.Content.CopyTo(myBytes,0); 
//Uh oh! touched it again, copying a zero'd array.
```

or when you were debugging and you stuck a watch variable on the property or accidentally hovered your mouse over the property.

Is this kind of mechanism an accepted or prevalent way of using properties for streamed data.

Comment: Whilst you've taken some time on the question, I don't think there can be a constructive answer.

Comment: yeah it is a little bit "subjective" in terms of asking for opinions. maybe I'm just venting frustration on SO this morning :-) if it's closed. so be it.

Comment: Instead of complaining here you could create a unit test and open a bug at the project, then others might benefit from your experience.

Comment: Its a good question. And it does have a very constructive answer. It relates to best practices in writing clear maintainable code. 
You can clearly see from the answers that there actually is a consensus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very *very* poor code.

The general wisdom is that properties should not affect the inner state of an object. If you call set, then get you should always get back the value you've just set. If you call get twicwe, you should get the same result twice.

This should have been a method called `GetContent` at very least, but id still expect to be able to call that method repeatedly and get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

This is very poor code. 
Properties should contain very little logic, and by no means cause side effects.

This property would be better of as a *method* named getNextContent.

Answer (score 2):

Its bad code, it breaks a thing called Command Query Separation ( CQS ).

The idea being that a query should be repeatable without any side effects.   Commands / Actions shouldn't really provide any info about an object, just make a modification. (though in practice it can be done for chaining commands)

Answer (score 1):

Its poor code, obviously, and I haven't seen it much.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is terrible code for exactly the reasons you gave.

Answer (score 1):

You should file a bug. Regardless of how unlikely it is that they will fix it.